# Select Multiple items in ng-repeat and Send The object to Addtocart functionality of ng-cart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shopping-cart

I am having a scenario where I have repeat items list with having check box on each item and "Select All" functionality also on page header section and if either I select one item or select all (Multiple), the add to cart button gets activated( Default disable and enable when any item in the list is checked or selected ) . 
But now the point is `Addtocart` functionality of ng-cart directive is written in a way that the `Addtocart` button should be on each item in list., but the scenario that I have is that I have to first check either one item or multiple then having only one `Addtocart` button to make or add single or multiple items added in one go .

Help me with this.

Resources : 
https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart

Answer (score 0):

As given in the [**documentation**](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs) and also the [**source code**](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/blob/master/src/ngCart.js), there is a method `addItem` on `ngCart` service which can be used to add items to the cart like :

```
ngCart.addItem(id, name, price, quantity, data);
```

So, In your case, once you check if one/more items are checked, you can call this method by looping through each of your checked items.

Make sure you add the module `ngCart` in your app module dependencies and the service `ngCart` in your Controller to access all the shared methods of the service.

Make below changes to get it working :

**docListView.html** :

```
// Added this button for testing

<button ng-click="addItem()">AddToCart</button>
```

**docListController.js** :

```
//Inject 'ngCart' service in the controller as a dependency.

docListController.$inject = ["$scope", "ngCart"];

//function that will be called when `AddToCart` button is clicked,
//where each selected item is added to the cart.

$scope.addItem = function (){

  angular.forEach($scope.seletedDocumentsCollection.selectedValues, function (selectedItem) {

   ngCart.addItem(selectedItem.isbn, selectedItem.login, selectedItem.price);

  });
}
```

Comment: I got your point , but the addtocart button is on every list item on each button click we are calling addItem function and pushing single object in cart . Right? , But the scenario that I have is I am only one add to cart button on my header and having check box on each item , on select or either single or multiple checkbox I have to pass multiple items at once to Addtocart button which is global kept on header of my page .hope u got my point

Comment: That is not a button, it is defined as a service in `ngCart` module. If you check the source code of `ngAddToCart` directive, it is also using the same method to add the item.

Comment: @AttamjotSingh: i got your point, you can loop through each item of the checked items and call the `addItem` method as shown above which will add each item to the cart.

Comment: Can u please create a jsfiddle example for me , will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I can do that but If you can add the code that you already have written in a fiddle and share it , I'll update it with the solution.

Comment: Ok I can share you the code over e-mail , please share your email id . Hope it's fine with you.

Comment: Otherwise, Share your screen if you have team viewer ?

Comment: Not having Suzo , I can share you the code over Dropbox or email whichever you like . Can share the Dropbox link over here

Comment: Share the dropbox link over here

Comment: Dear Suzo, Please have a look at the following dropbox link and let me know if concerns. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkde8iodwfoei93/ShoppingCart_home.zip?dl=0

Comment: @AttamjotSingh: I've updated your code , please check and confirm. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sng8b85szduhsp4/ShoppingCart_home.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please check `docListController.js` and `docListView.html`. I've added a custom button in the view below your addToCart button to test. Change it as  per your requirement. Also, I've added an `addItem` function in the controller which adds each item to the cart using `ngCart's addItem service`. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: The customzied addtoCart button is working fine that you developed, but i want you to replicate the same functionality in ngcart-addtocart directive. and i don't want quantity functionality, setTax, setShipping to be added to the cart. Please make the changes to the code that you shared. Thanks for your great help. @suzo

Comment: And i need one more functionality which is more important then all this that once the item/items gets added to the cart , the user should not be able to able to again check the item/items that gets added to the cart till its either removed from the cart. Thanks for your great help

Comment: @AttamjotSingh I'm sorry, but I can't do your whole project here, I hope I have answered the question you have asked in the OP. If you want anything else, try implementing it and post another question if you are stuck somewhere doing. Happy coding :)